# Angular electron - Change event not triggering for file upload

Tags: javascript, angular, electron, angular6

am working on an Electron App which used Angular 5. I have code for a file upload

```
<input type="file" name="logochange" id="change-logo" accept="image/png, image/jpg" (change)="changeLogo()" />
```

and the changeLogo() function in the TS file as below

```
changeLogo() {
    alert('logo changed');
}
```

Problem: The 'change' event is firing if I run 'ng serve' and test from browser. But if I make electron app (npm run electron-windows). The same 'change' event not firing. Why it is working in normal angular but not with an electron?

Your directions will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Ref: https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/

Add Change detector:
May be your code is ouside angular zone while using electron

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';

 constructor( private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { 
 this.ref.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: this.ref.detectChanges();  put this onChange event

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: check here :https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/